# Value is not changed in a map?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, foreach, scope

I change the value of `line[s]` to remove all `;` outside the map but inside the map `line[s]` still has `;` in it.

```js
const keys = Object.keys(x[0]);
csv += `${keys.join(',')}\n`;

x.forEach((line) => {
  line[s] = line['s'].replace(';', '%3B')
  console.log(line.signalFormula)
  csv += `${keys.map((key) => line[key]).join(',')}\n`;
})
```

Update 
my code now looks like this

```
const keys = Object.keys(x[0]);
        csv += `${keys.join(';')}\n`;
        x.forEach((line) => {
          line[keys[2]] = line[keys[2]].split(';').join('%3B');
          console.log(line[keys[2]])
          csv += `${keys.map((key) => line[key]).join(';')}\n`;
        }
```

console.log(line[keys[2]]) this gives the correct value but in the file it is not correct.

Comment: Is `s` a variable? `line[s]` and `line['s']` are different things.

Comment: if a line has more than one `;` your code will only replace the first `;` with a `%3B`

Answer (score 0):

if x is a array of objects containing some string in key 's'. 
change

```
line[s] = line['s'].replace(';', '%3B')
```

to

```
line['s'] = line['s'].replace(';', '%3B')
```